# Reaching functions without needing to write "Class.Function()"

Tags: c#

Simple question. How do I reach functions between classes without having to write the class name.

Instead of Class.Function(), I want it to be Function() only, even though that function is in another class.

```
public class Class1
{
    public static void Function1()
    {
        // Code
    }
}
```

to

```
public partial class Class2 : Form
{
    public static void Function2() 
    {
        Function1();
    }
}
```

Without having to do the following:

```
public partial class Class2 : Form
{
    public static void Function2() 
    {
        Class1.Function1();
    }
}
```

Comment: If the `Function` is a static member of `Class`, then you can get rid of the `Class` if you use a [`using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) directive like the suggestion in the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75122118/3110834), but if `Function` is an instance member it doesn't make sense, you need a variable pointing to the instance, then call it like `xxxx.Function()`.

Comment: It is static, but as my comment states below, I couldn't quite figure out how to use the example.

Comment: Then you need to share a [MCVE] to help people helping you rather guessing what your code look like.

Comment: Updated my post with some minimal code.

Comment: @Farrow - Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Enigmativity Because I want to clean up my code. I have a lot of references to that class

Comment: @Farrow - It sounds to me like you've got a `Utilities` or `Functions` class that just contains a lot of general purpose functions. If that's the case, you have a design issue, not unclean code. Removing the reference to the `Class1` class will shorten your code, but I'd argue that it makes it less maintainable and could introduce bugs and constraints that you don't want. I'd suggest you post a question showing the actual code you're really working with and see if we can provide an alternative..

Comment: @Enigmativity Not entirely right. But I suppose you wouldn't know since I didn't share my code. It's just a bit much to paste into a question on stack overflow. It's a class named InputHandler for handling the input from the forms.

Comment: @Farrow - Tat's why we like the actual code pasted in the question. It makes it clear why you're doing things. I would still like to see the code.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done as follows (I provided a sample namespace):

```
using static Some.Namespace.Class;
```

More at MS Learn: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#static-modifier

... and a minor detail: in C# we usually speak of *methods*, not *functions*. I don't know why, that's just how it is.

Comment: I saw something simlilar when googling, but I didn't quite figure out the "Some" or the "Namespace". Also, I mostly deal with programming in swedish, so I didn't know the methods thing, but will keep that in mind in the future! Thanks for telling me!